# Design patterns: helper class in front of Factory

Tags: design-patterns

Say, I've got a `NotificationServiceFactory` class with `getService(Enum notificationType)` method.

But in most cases there is just `notificationId` as the input, without `notificationType`.

So, i have to invoke some sort of Helper class to retrieve Notification from database by id, than run `getService(Enum notificationType)` and finally invoke desired method on obtained service.

Pseudocode:

```
class NotificationController() {

    private NotificationServiceHelper helper;

    void processNotification(Long notificationId) {
        helper.processNotification(notificationId);
    }   
}

class NotificationServiceHelper() {

    private NotificationServiceFactory factory;
    private NotificationRepository repository;

    void processNotification(Long notificationId) {
        Notification notification = repository.find(notificationId);
        factory.getService(notification.getType()).processNotification(notification);
    }
}
```

What is this NotificationServiceHelper class? Facade? Adapter?

Is that a bad practice, or just a standard approach?

Comment: It's just another stateless service... the design seems weird however. Could you expand a bit more on the real business problem here?

Comment: I have to implement several Notification Services, because each type of notification should be handled separetly (no common logic, just common interface). But as an input, I always get notificationId, so there is no way to choose proper service without a helper.

Comment: This really isn't facade, since you really aren't 'wrapping' or 'hiding' anything, nor is it 'adapter' since you are not 'converting one API to match another' (I've had long discussions about wrapper-facade pattern with one of the authors of the POSA books (my phd adviser)) I don't really see anything special in the way you've implemented it offhand, but  I'll think about it for a few more minutes...

Comment: Actually, I think this may be a Facade after all. It's role is to simplify the calling code so it doesn't have to know about all the subsystems at play, where the factory and the various concrete notification processors can be viewed as subsystems.

Comment: What does it mean to process a notification btw, if there's no interaction with infrastructure services you may place the logic directly in the type itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No This is not Facade nor is it Adapter. You are not [A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger body of code] from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern nor are you (too lazy to look up wiki definition of Adapter, but... converting one API of a class to match a new desired API.

If anything this is actually closer to the Command Processor Pattern http://wiki.hsr.ch/APF/files/CommandProcessor.pdf

Where the 'notification' is the 'command' that you are 'processing'

You have:

1) a controller that accepts service requests (here your 'helper' but I would rename it to match pattern)

2) the idea of an 'abstract command' being 'a notification that uses some service'

3) a lookup to retrieve the notification(concrete command instance) from ...somewhere... via using the ID (just because all 'notifications' currently are the same class doesn't mean they don't have member data which identifies which service they should use (obviously they do with notification.getType())

SO you could easily make this...

'notificationController' (formerly the helper) (controller) this class actually builds the concrete commands and then passes them to the 'command processor' for 'processing' So this is where you would build your NotificationA and NotificationB class instances by passing in the notificationID and then using a factory to build the 'appropriate' class instance returned as a 'notification'

'command processor' (also sorta formerly the helper) but this class would actually invoke the commands. and (if you so desire, store a queue of past commands to enable an 'undo' functionality' (this has to be built into the commands too))

'abstract notification' (base class/interface for all notifications) (abstract command)

'concrete notification classes' for each notification type (command(s))

'services' (the 'supplier' in the paper's usage, but basically the unique code that operates upon a command stored inside the command itself, but invoked from  the command processor on the 'command' )

This pattern is a bit complicated, and I'm probably not doing it justice at all right now, but rushed and thought it might help before I have to leave.

Comment: This pattern 'hides' the logic of the (service identification) inside the command creation and (service invoking) inside the command. This simplifies your command processor and allows you to isolate any 'special sauce' that might be unique for a particular command type/service into just one command class. (You have a trade off of more classes but generally simpler classes that are much more focused) (I find this trade-off WELL worth the effort often)

Comment: Why wouldn't be a Facade? "A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger body of code" that's actually exactly what it does, hiding away the factory and the various concrete processors at play.

Comment: @plalx Because it is only encloses 2 method calls, and those calls are to _2_ different classes. Only having 2 methods makes it not facade by like ~70%, and then to two different classes is ~30% for my 'opinion' about it NOT being facade pattern. Facade 'wraps' some larger body of code and simplifies it, but... here it is a 'scale' issue, we are only 'simplifying' 2 method calls, not the entire 2 classes, so if this class simplified a bunch of method calls from related class(es) then it would "feel" more like the facade pattern. Perhaps.... [1/2]

Comment: Perhaps.... it fits the most broad definition of the facade pattern. But it is such a simple class, that doesn't really need to 'be a class' could just have the two method calls (if only called once), or a class method of controller (if called multiple times). At most this 'misused' a pattern(if the class was 'only' what they showed here) This is why I recommended the Command Processor pattern, it is clearer in its goals/uses. Plus you then put the logic inside the command(notification(s)) and you don't have to have this semi-ambiguous class.[2/2]